# Libgdx mask by shader with different textures

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

I'm following this tutorial

https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/ShaderLesson4

to create mask technique in libgdx. Everything works fine as the example code.

But the example code only use
a set of (background, mask, foreground) texture. When applying in my case with different set of textures, I cannot get it works unless
using batch.flush() after batch.draw(tex0,...).

The cycle is:

```
batch.begin()
tex1 = foreground1;
tex2 = mask1;
tex1.bind(1);
tex2.bind(2);
Gdx.gl.glActiveTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE0);
batch.draw(tex0, ...)
batch.flush();

tex1 = foreground2;
tex2 = mask2;
tex1.bind(1);
tex2.bind(2);
Gdx.gl.glActiveTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE0);
batch.draw(tex0, ...)
batch.flush();
batch.end();
```

If I don't use batch.flush(), all masks and foregrounds will be identical. But using batch.flush() severely reducing performance when I test on my Android phone.
Thanks in advance, any help is highly appreciated

Comment: So you have two different masks you want to apply. You need to submit all the sprites that will be masked by the first mask first before the first flush, and then submit all the other sprites before the second flush. Then you will only be flushing twice.

Comment: I understand your idea that only use flush() when the texture is changed. So it is best to use only one texture for all masks & foregrounds, isn't right?
But I don't know how to change different masks & foregrounds if using only one Texture (just as using differentTextureRegions in only one Texture). 
So I have to separate all masks & foregrounds into different Textures and lead to this problem

Comment: If you have one mask for every sprite, is there any reason you can't mask the sprites directly in some paint program ahead of time? Even if you are able to put everything into one texture, you are still using three texture lookups for each fragment, which could have a very significant performance impact.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation but I want to use dynamic mask. So is there another better solution to achieve the mask effect ?

Comment: I would have to know exactly what you're trying to achieve. You might be able to change the draw order and blend modes or use FrameBuffers in a clever way to get what you want.